# Why can't I take screenshots in Android Emulator after installing Genymotion?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion

I've installed Genyomtion android emulator. Then I realized I can't take screenshots in Eclipse DDMS view.
After that, I tried to take a screenshot with standard android emulator that comes with the SDK. It didn't work.
Eclipse shows me a black image instead of screenshot.
It worked before I installed Genymotion! It's suspicious that Genymotion hacked my ADB, because screenshot taking is part of PAID version of GenyMotion!

Has anyone experienced the same problem? How can I get Eclipse taking screenshots again without reinstalling it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a known bug on 4.3 images, they are working on a fix. On a 4.2.2 image it's working for me, you can try to create a 4.2.2 device to take screenshot in the meantime.

Source: On twitter @genymotion responded to @Littledot1230 on this question :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Finally I've tried with a 4.2 image and it works fine! Thank you, helped a lot!

Comment: 4.3.x and 4.4.x images are not working on the emulators for screenshots. 4.2.2 worked for me - slowly, but it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I have just used Genymotion and Eclipse DDMS today to take a screenshot for an app store submission.

So it works on at least these versions on my Win8 Pro machine:

- Genymotion v1.1.0
- Android 4.2.2 10" image
- Eclipse ADT v22.0.1

Edit: [so 4.2.2 is why mine worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20034206/383414) - thanks [Bonrry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475092/bonrry)